# What is the purpose of `constant.js` in d3-drag library?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, ecmascript-6

In having a bit of a look at the [source code](https://github.com/d3/d3-drag/tree/master/src) for the `d3-drag` javascript (es6) module, I've noticed there is a file called `constant.js` whose entire contents are:

```
export default function(x) {
  return function() {
    return x;
  };
}
```

This is imported in `drag.js`:

```
import constant from "./constant";
```

and then used (showing one of three similar instances):

```
drag.container = function(_) {
    return arguments.length ? (container = typeof _ === "function" ? _ : constant(_), drag) : container;
  };
```

Perhaps I just don't fully grok javascript in all its callback glory, but I don't quite understand the purpose of the `constant.js` module. Is someone able to shed a little light as to what's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, let's step through it

```
export default function(x) {
  return function() {
    return x;
  };
}
```

is a function that will return a function resulting in the argument to the first, e.g.

```
var fn = constant(4);
fn() === 4;
```

Now let's look at

```
drag.container = function(_) {
  return arguments.length 
    ? (container = typeof _ === "function" ? _ : constant(_), drag)
    : container;
};
```

Note, this uses a variable `container` that is not declared here, and exists in an outer scope. There are two parts going on, one is that the result depend on the usage pattern, and the other depends on the type passed in. So let's split it up more:

```
var container;

drag.container = function(_) {
  if (arguments.length > 0) {
    if (typeof _ === "function") {
      container = _;
    } else {
      container = constant(_);
    }
    return drag;
  } else {
    return container;
  }
};
```

- When `.container()` is called with no arguments, the current value of the `container` variable is returned.
- When `.container(foo)` is called, if `foo` is a function, that function becomes the `container` value, and if it is called without a function, `constant` is used to create a function that returns the non-function value `foo`.

So `constant` combine with `typeof` means that `container` is guaranteed to always be a function that returns a value.